# Measurable functions with non measurable image

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am just curious about examples of measurable functions $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ such that $f[0,1]$ is not measurable.

This is motivated by the question [Is measure preserving function almost surjective?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296651/is-measure-preserving-function-almost-surjective/297480#297480), that asks whether such maps have image of inner measure one. The solution is trivial if $f[0,1]$ is measurable, however, I have not succeeded understanding ``how bad'' it could be assuming that $f[0,1]$ is measurable.

I think it is not possible to construct any such $f$ avoiding the use of the axiom of choice (because if not, it would be possible to construct a non measurable set $A=f[0,1]$ without it). On the other hand, if we start from a non-measurable set $V,$ and we try to find $f$ such that $f[0,1]=V,$ then I do not know how to make such $f$ to be measurable.

---

What about examples examples of measurable functions $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ such that $f[0,1]=A\cup B$ where $A$ is not Lebesgue, $B$ has Lebesgue measure zero and $f^{-1}A$ has strictly positive Lebesgue measure?

Comment: If your function doesn't have to be measure preserving, you can just take a function that maps a measure zero set with the cardinality of the continuum (the Cantor set, say) onto some nonmeasurable set and maps everything else to $0$. That function will be Lebesgue measurable but have nonmeasurable range.

Comment: This is a good idea. Is the non Lebesgue measurable set a Borel set? If it is not, then I understand your example, if it is, then I do not understand it...

Comment: @user39115 If $V$ is not Lebesgue measurable, then it cannot be Borel since all Borel sets are Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: If I understand correctly, basically the examples are: send a Lebesgue measurable set of measure zero of cardinality continuum onto a non-measurable set and the complement onto a Lebesgue measurable set of measure zero.

Comment: A note: your function $f$ cannot be Borel.  The image of $[0,1]$ (or any Borel set) under any Borel function is an [analytic set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set), and analytic sets are always Lebesgue measurable (indeed, universally measurable), though they need not be Borel.  In particular, modifying your function on a null set can make the image measurable.  So such a function has to map a null set to a non-measurable set.

Comment: Many thanks. As you say such a function has to map a null set to a non measurable set, I guess:  Any measurable and computable map in the unit interval sends Borel sets to Lebesgue sets?

Comment: @user39115 Regarding the last question. It is possible to construct such a function. Just the construction from my answer needs to be slightly adjusted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A measurable function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ maps Lebesgue measurable sets to measurable sets if and only if it has a Lusin property: the image of a set of measure zero has measure zero.

Here is an example when the Lusin property is violated. 
Take a Cantor set of positive Lebesgue measure in $[0,1]$. This set contains a non-measurable subset $E$. Let $F$ be a subset of the ternary Cantor set that is homeomorphic to $E$. Since the ternary Cantor set has measure zero, $F$ is measurable (and of measure zero). Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be defined as a homeomorphism of $F$ onto $E$ and a constant map (with the value in $E$) on the complement of $F$. The mapping $f$ is measurable and $f([0,1])=E$ is not measurable.

EDIT: I have just realized that my answer is very similar to the comment of Michael Greinecker.